# How can I call from my PC?

Tags: voip, phone

Is there a way to just take a number of some web page and dial it?  Perhaps route it via my iPhone?  The scenario I am talking about is this:  let's say I am looking for an apartment on craigslist.  it lists a phone number.  I'd like to be able to call that number without having to go and get my phone.

I'd like a solution that does not involve any more monthly fees, charges, etc...

Comment: I don't think there are any solutions without costs, if you're willing to have costs you'll have several possibilities, with Skype being the most popular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Chrome as your browser, then you can get a Google Voice account and the Google Voice extension. Then you'll be able to click on a number and it will route it to your phone.

Comment: You can also add your Google Chat account to Google Voice and you don't even have to go get your phone.

Comment: Yes that's true, but wont that incur a fee?

Comment: It's free for calls to the United States, otherwise you get charged, yeah: http://www.google.com/chat/voice/

Comment: Alright, cool. That's good to know. This sounds like the best option then.